# Node stream get write after end error

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, stream, gzip

I'm testing stream to upload and download files, below is my realy simple file download route that unzip my compressed file and send it via stream :

```
app.get('/file', (req, res) => {   
   fs.createReadStream('./upload/compress_aurelien-boquet.pdf')
      .pipe(unzip)
      .pipe(res); 
});
```

I'm using express 4.15.2 btw.

When i try this route it works fine the first time and shows me the pdf on my browser, but if I refresh the page then my server get this error :

```
events.js:163
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: write after end
    at writeAfterEnd (_stream_writable.js:191:12)
    at Unzip.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:238:5)
    at ReadStream.ondata (_stream_readable.js:557:20)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at ReadStream.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:178:18)
    at ReadStream.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:136:10)
    at onread (fs.js:1938:12)
    at FSReqWrap.wrapper [as oncomplete] (fs.js:629:17)
```

I would like to know what's going on ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My bad, was using zlib library to gzip and unzip file but I forgot that "zlib.createGzip" and "zlib.createUnzip" return a stream so I was reusing an already ended stream causing me the 'write after end error'.

The bad thing I was doing :

```
const unzip = zlib.createUnzip();

app.get('/file', (req, res) => {   
   fs.createReadStream('./upload/compress_aurelien-boquet.pdf')
      .pipe(unzip)
      .pipe(res); 
});
```

The good thing to do :

```
app.get('/file', (req, res) => {

   fs.createReadStream('./upload/compress_aurelien-boquet.pdf')
      .pipe(zlib.createGunzip())
      .pipe(res);

});
```